# Named arguments and the arguments object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Recently I started learning JavaScript through Nicholas C. Zakas' book Professional JavaScript For Web Developers and I came across some questions that I could not solve by myself.

As the title says, that's all about **named arguments** and **arguments object** in JavaScript functions.

E.g. we have this piece of code:

```
function doAdd(num1 , num2) {
     arguments[1] = 10;
     alert(arguments[0] + num2);
}

doAdd(10 , 20);
```

The book says that values in the arguments object are automatically reflected by the corresponding named arguments, so `num2` enters the function with a value of **20** and then it gets overwritten via `arguments[1]` and finally gets a value of **10**.All  good all clear up to this point. Then it says that

> this effect goes only one way: changing the named argument does not result in a change to the corresponding value in arguments.

And that's where the problems start.

I tried to modify this code a bit to understand what the author says but I failed.

E.g.

```
function doAdd(num1 , num2) {
     arguments[1] = 10;
     num2 = 40;
     alert(arguments[0] + arguments[1]);
}

doAdd(10 , 20);
```

This time `num2` enters function with a value of **20** again, it changes to **10** via `arguments[1]` and then it changes once more to **40** via the named argument `num2` this time. Alert pops up **50**, since a change to a **named** argument does not result in a change to the corresponding value in `arguments`. Why does alert not pop up **20**?

Comment: Mr. Zakas' book is in error.

Comment: I am reading the book and I got the same question... thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the book assumes you're using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

If you run the code in strict mode, you'll get the behavior you'd expect given what's written in the book.

```
function doAdd(num1 , num2) {
     "use strict";
     arguments[1] = 10;
     num2 = 40;
     alert(arguments[0] + arguments[1]);
}
doAdd(10 , 20); // this alerts 20, alerts 50 in nonstrict mode
```

A little known fact is that the entire point of strict mode is to avoid this sort of dynamic scoping (which is why arguments is fixated, `with` isn't allowed and `eval` behaves differently). Aside from clarity gains, this allows for massive speed improvements.

Also see [this](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6):

> For strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object‘s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values.

This is what NCZ means in context, quoting the book itself:

> Strict mode makes several changes to how the arguments object can be used. First, assignment, 
>   as in the previous example, no longer works. The value of num2 remains undefined even though 
>   arguments[1] has been assigned to 10. Second, trying to overwrite the value of arguments is a 
>   syntax error. (The code will not execute.) - Page 82, Language Basics, Professional JavaScript, Nicholas C. Zakas

Comment: It was an answer attempt , i'm sry i just fixed it.

Comment: @user3649693 Please leave your uncertainties as a comment then, so I can respond to it - for future visitors.

Comment: But aren't we over writting the value of arguments[1] (which is 10) with the value of num2 (which is 40) ? Book assumes we are stict mode but there is no syntax error and script runs smooth.This kinda confuses me.

Comment: @user3649693 reassigning arguments means `arguments = []` or something like that. Assigning to a property of arguments means code that looks like `arguments[1] = 10` , while this is allowed, it changes a _copy_ of the argument, and not the argument itself.

Comment: This is a bit less confusing right now. How could we alter that piece of code above so it would throw a syntax error in strict mode?

Comment: @user3649693 `arguments = [arguments[0],10]` instead of `arguments[1] = 10` would do the trick.

Comment: if we are calling our function and passing in our arguments like this
`doAdd(10 , 20);` adding the line of code you posted (`arguments = [arguments[0],10]`) would mean that `arguments[0]` remains as it is (10) but `arguments[1]` (which is 20) is changing to 10?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I'm sorry for that long delay between my answers , i have been busy yesterday.Just to sum up , in non-strict mode , `named arguments` and `arguments object` are dynamically pointing at each other , meaning that a change of a `named argument` would change the corresponding `arguments[number]` value and vise versa. While in strict-mode this does not happen because values passed in a function are just `copies` right?

Comment: Yes, that's what the specification I quoted says and the example shows. If you feel the issue is resolved please consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Issue is solved , you were clear enough , thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [ECMA 5.1 Specifications for Arguments Object](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6),

> **NOTE 1** For **non-strict mode functions** the array index (defined in 15.4) named data properties of an arguments object whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s execution context. **This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa.**

It didn't alert 20 because, as per the ECMA 5.1 specifications, in a non-strict mode function, mutating arguments object with the numeric key, will also change actual formal parameter corresponding to the numeric key.

In your case, when you change `arguments[1]`, you are also changing the second parameter. The same way, when you change `num2`, you are also changing `arguments[1]`.